# Why is valgrind complaining about the perfectly fine initialized buffer?

Tags: valgrind, glibc

This is the test code "valgrind.c". It initializes an on stack buffer, then does a simple string compare over it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <string.h>


int  main( void)
{
   char   buf[ 6];

   memset( buf, 'X', sizeof( buf));
   if( strncmp( buf, "XXXX", 4))
      abort();

   return( 0);
}
```

I compile this with `cc -O0 -g valgrind.c -o valgrind`.
Running on its own, it does fine.
When I run it through `valgrind --track-origins=yes ./valgrind` though this gives me:

```
==28182== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28182== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==28182==    at 0x4E058CC: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so)
==28182==    by 0x4CAA09A: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so)
==28182==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==28182==    at 0x4CA9FBD: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so)
```

That really makes no sense to me. I am running this on Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: The warning messages have nothing to do with your buffer (probably); they have to do with code in the C library, over which your program has very little control.

Comment: If I make buf static though, the error doesn't show up, which I find curious. Though I would concur that there is really no problem in my code.

Comment: Without the proper stack backtrace information, it is hard to tell.  The traces don't tell me whether the problem is detected before your main function is entered, or during it (which only leaves `memset()` and `strncmp()` as candidate problem makers), or after it.  The prologue code on a Mac is extensive and leaky/flaky according to Valgrind. You end up with numerous suppressions for it.  Was the Valgrind build for the current version of your o/s?  That has caused problems on occasion on macOS — could it be a factor here?

Comment: I am using what Ubuntu offers me through apt-get. So one would hope it is coherent, but it apparently isn't. I think the general reason why this problem appears has been explained by Florian in the thread below.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that the *valgrind* libraries were buggy. After a complete dist-upgrade, things work now as expected. The version number of valgrind and the executable remain the same though (my current dpkg number is now 1:3.13.0-2ubuntu6, I forgot to jot down the old one, sorry).

These were the strace opened libraries with their shasums. Thre is actually a difference in libraries opened and you can see that the libc and the actual test and valgrind executable are unchanged in both scenarios:

Broken:

```
41bd206c714bcd2be561b477d756a4104dddd2d3578040cca30ff06d19730d61  /etc/ld.so.cache
b0d9f1bc02b4500cff157d16b2761b9b2420151cc129de37ccdecf6d3005a1e0  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
b0d9f1bc02b4500cff157d16b2761b9b2420151cc129de37ccdecf6d3005a1e0  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so
701e316140eda639d651efad20b187a0811ea4deac0a52f8bcd322dffbb29d94  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so
701e316140eda639d651efad20b187a0811ea4deac0a52f8bcd322dffbb29d94  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
38705bdbed45a77c2de28bedf5560d6ca016d57861bf60caa42255ceab8f076a  /tmp/valgrind
4652774bd116cb49951ef74115ad4237cad5021b2bd4d80002f09d986ec438b9  /usr/bin/valgrind
0369719ef5fe66d467a385299396bab0937002694ffc78027ede22c09d39abf3  /usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp
16b5f1e6ae25663620edb8f8d4a7f1a392e059d6cf9eb20a270129295548ffb2  /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
6335747b07b2e8a6150fbfa777ade9bd80d56626bba9772d61c7d33328e68bda  /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
827b4c18aefad7788b6e654b1519d3caa1ab223cf7a6ba58d22d7ad7d383b032  /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
38705bdbed45a77c2de28bedf5560d6ca016d57861bf60caa42255ceab8f076a  ./valgrind
```

Healthy:

```
b0d9f1bc02b4500cff157d16b2761b9b2420151cc129de37ccdecf6d3005a1e0  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
b0d9f1bc02b4500cff157d16b2761b9b2420151cc129de37ccdecf6d3005a1e0  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so
701e316140eda639d651efad20b187a0811ea4deac0a52f8bcd322dffbb29d94  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so
701e316140eda639d651efad20b187a0811ea4deac0a52f8bcd322dffbb29d94  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
38705bdbed45a77c2de28bedf5560d6ca016d57861bf60caa42255ceab8f076a  /tmp/valgrind
4652774bd116cb49951ef74115ad4237cad5021b2bd4d80002f09d986ec438b9  /usr/bin/valgrind
391826262f9dc33565a8ac0b762ba860951267e73b0b4db7d02d1fd62782f8c8  /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so
3ab1f160af6c3198de45f286dd569fad7ae976a89ff1655e955ef0544b8b5d6c  /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so
ae4ea44f87787b9b80d19a69ad287195dc7840eea08c08732d36d2ef1e6ecff3  /usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp
ba18f39979d22efc89340b839257f953a505ef5ca774b5bf06edd78ecb6ed86e  /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
1649637bba73e84b962222f3756cc810c5413239ed180e0029cd98f069612613  /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
ab1501fa569e0185dea7248648255276ca965bbe270803dcbb930a22ea7a59b7  /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
38705bdbed45a77c2de28bedf5560d6ca016d57861bf60caa42255ceab8f076a  ./valgrind
```

Thanks for the helpful comments, especially from Florian, which put me on the right track.